# AJAX in SCORM content

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2

I'm new to SCORM, I'm planning to implement an export-to-SCORM feature.
Currently, playing the content (which is not a SCORM player) is like a small HTML5 web app, and as part of its implementation, it uses features like AJAX for example to lazy load some files (JS files, CSS files).

I was thinking to just have a way to use the same player code when creating the SCORM course.

Are SCORM courses required to work offline or from disk?

If that's the case, using the techniques, like the lazy load I described above, won't work.

I imagine there could be some SCORM player mobile apps which store and load SCORM course on the device and a web-server is not available so that AJAX could work. (Or are these mobile apps actually implementing a local web-server within themselves in order to play the SCORM content?)

AFAIK, SCORM 1.2 or 2004 doesn't specifically put any restriction whether AJAX could be used in the presentation layer of the SCORM content, but in practice, when content is played in a player it obviously matters.

Answer (score 1):

SCORM courses are not *required* to work offline or from disk (depending on what that means), which isn't to say they can't. SCORM courses are expected to load the initial resource from the location that they've been imported to, so while AJAX to a different location could work there are issues with security (credentials can't be secured or trusted), 3rd party loading, etc. Unless you were going to AJAX back to the loading host to retrieve content shipped with the package which should work and there are mechanisms that can be used to increase security for content retrieval.

The one offline implementation of a SCORM player that I'm familiar with (Rustici Software's) requires the packages to be all inclusive because there is no web server available. Again, that isn't to say that it couldn't be implemented with one, just that I'm not aware that such a thing has been implemented.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm referring to the AJAX back to the loading host to retrieve content shipped with the package. It might sounds strange why not just load it without AJAX and the reason is related to how I'm implementing the export to SCORM, it's just easier to use the existing player for my content (non SCORM).

Comment: My question has to do with how a SCORM player loads the content, not if the player itself works offline or not. Technically, the SCORM player could have a local webserver and fetch the SCORM content from it. Not sure if it makes sense

Comment: In your example with Rustici: technically, an iOS or Android app can load the HTML (stored on the device disk) in a web-view control. That's one simple approach. In this scenario, using AJAX in my SCORM content won't work because there's no web server

Comment: That's why I was asking if the SCORM content is meant to work without a web-server. I hope it's clearer, sorry.

Comment: Generally the SCORM player is *only* responsible for loading the initial resource, so the HTML file, any additional resources are outside the control of the SCORM player so will load however allowed by where that initial page was executed. So an AJAX request back to a relative path resolvable from the initial page should work, unless the initial load of that thing doesn't allow such requests because itself wasn't "hosted" (IOW `file://`, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the restrictions on the protocol which AJAX has. That's the reason of my question.